# How do I use my laptops wifi connection on my desktop?

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint, network-shares, internet-connection

I recently acquired a pretty decent desktop which I installed windows 10 onto, the only fallback is the wifi card isnt very powerful so it keeps dropping its connection while my laptop continues fast download speeds. I'm wondering if it is possible to connect to my laptop with an ethernet cord and use it for my internet connection. I'm running linux mint (debian) on my laptop. Any help is greatly appreciated, ive googled it but I cannot seem to find anything that is overly clear.

Comment: You're asking an XY question.  Are you really going to turn on the laptop just to use the desktop? Why not improve the WiFi reception on the desktop?  BTW it's "drawback" not *"fallback"*.

Comment: i said any HELP would be appreciated, go away

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a bridge on the laptop. Basically, connection comes into the wifi and out the NIC on the laptop. Link below for instructions.

https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Bridging_with_a_wireless_NIC

Comment: ok, im going through the steps and it says to add the interface the leads to the internet connection but im am not allowed to wlan0 (my wireless card) to br0. I created another bridge called br1 and it gives me the same thing "operation not permitted"

Comment: i read further down the page and found i was using instructions for using a wired connection. im still having issues but im working in a new direction